# In R using if else loop how to extract even and odd nubers

Tags: r, if-statement

I have a data of 500 ids which is stored in uid column ;I want to extract even ids and odd ids separately and store it in two different data respectively. How to do it in R using If-Else loop ?

Comment: Have you tried any of the methods listed here: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2010-July/244299.html

Comment: yes i've tried my query is it possible to do it using if -else loop in R

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't do it with an if-else loop. You use subsetting, with an expression based on whether the ID is odd or even.

```
odd  <- df[df$uid %% 2 == 1, ]
even <- df[df$uid %% 2 == 0, ]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Mr Hong 
Can you help me doing it same using if loop in R

Comment: @RaviRaghava using `[` is the `R` idiom, the fastest and simplest to way to do this kind of thing in `R`. If for some reason your actual use-case can't use this kind of subsetting, please ask another question with more specific detail.